# How to use Delve recent documents concept to display on any of SharePoint page in a web part?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, delve

For one of the Projects I am working on, the client has a requirement to use Delve Recent Documents concept. They are basically wanting to know if it would be possible to display the Recent Documents from Delve on to a SharePoint page possibly in a web part. Now, is this even possible? If anyone has an idea about this, please share.
For now I have a content search web part which kind of displays all the recent documents worked in the past 30 days sorted by LastModified Time, which works perfectly alright but I want to know if Delve can be leveraged as a replacement to what I have done.
Please note that the environment I am working with is Office365.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Delve was created using the Microsoft Graph.  If you search for Microsoft Graph there is a Graph Explorer page that will let you test the API.  I don't believe that you'll currently get the exact same results but you'll see that you can pull from OneDrive, Outlook, SharePoint, etc.  You can even use their insights to pull content that is trending around you or the current user.